# What is the closed form of the infinite series $g(x) = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} x^{3^{r}}$ for $|x|<1$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-equations, analytic-number-theory

This series satisfies the following functional equatioin

$$(g(x))^{2} =2\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}g(x^{3^{r}+1})+g(x^{2})$$

We are working on a algebraic problem we have finally ended up with this series $g(x)$. We have not been successful in finding the closed form so far.

I have attached some of our work to find the closed form for the series $g(x)$

[image]

Comment: I strongly believe there is no closed form for this series

Comment: This is a well known example of a [lacunary function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) and there is almost certainly no closed form. It's also worth noting that $g(x)$ satisfies the much simpler functional equation $g(x^3)=g(x)-x^3$.

Comment: Related: There is a classic paper of Mahler that studies the series $\sum x^{2^r}$.